# Counting Distinct Items In Apache Pig

Tags: mysql, hadoop, apache-pig

I have a table user table with Schema

```
|Column 1 | USER ID |int|

|Column 2 |EMAIL|chararray|

|Column 3 |LANGUAGE |chararray|

|Column 4 |LOCATION |chararray|
```

and a transactional table with schema

```
|Column 1 | ID |int|

|Column 2 |PRODUCT|int|

|Column 3 |USER ID |int|

|Column 4 |PURCHASE AMOUNT |double|

|Coulmn 5 |DESCRIPTION |chararray|
```

Ques...Find out the count of each product in distinctive Locations.

I have written a pig script as following :-

```
user = LOAD '/tmp/users.txt' USING PigStorage ('    ')
AS (USER_ID:int, EMAIL:chararray, LANGUAGE:chararray, LOCATION:chararray);

transaction = LOAD '/tmp/transaction.txt' USING PigStorage ('   ')
AS (ID:int, PRODUCT:int,USER_ID:int, PURCHASE_AMOUNT:double,DESCRIPTION:chararray);

u1 = JOIN user by USER_ID, transaction by USER_ID;

u2 = GROUP u1 by LOCATION;

Result = FOREACH u2 GENERATE COUNT(u2.PRODUCT);

DUMP Result;
```

Error---ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: Pig script failed to parse:
 Invalid scalar projection: u2

This is what i am getting.

Answer (score 1):

In your script `Result = FOREACH u2 GENERATE COUNT(u2.PRODUCT);` is wrong. After the group by operation, data structure changes. You can find that with `describe u2`. Please try with following (I'm assuming the fields are comma separated in the txt file):

```
user = LOAD 'user.txt' USING PigStorage (',') AS (USER_ID:int, EMAIL:chararray, LANGUAGE:chararray, LOCATION:chararray);

transaction = LOAD 'transaction.txt' USING PigStorage (',') AS (ID:int, PRODUCT:int,USER_ID:int, PURCHASE_AMOUNT:double,DESCRIPTION:chararray);

u1 = JOIN user by USER_ID, transaction by USER_ID;

u2 = GROUP u1 by (LOCATION,PRODUCT);

Result = FOREACH u2 GENERATE FLATTEN(group) as (LOCATION,PRODUCT), COUNT($1);

DUMP Result;
```